# How to Trim special Characters in a String in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, trim

I want to trim the occurence of special characters  in a string

```
String  has :    
prevs: Case Number                                                                    
____________________
```

In this i want to remove -------- this dash from this string .I have tried like this :

```
NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-"];
    NSString *stringNew = [[previousString2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:trim] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
NSString *stringWithoutDash = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

Comment: @Thanks,Its Working

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *trimedString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression, the pattern `[\\s_]{4,}` searches for 4 and more whitespace or underscore characters.

```
NSString *trimmedString = [previousString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\s_]{4,}" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, previousString2.length)];
```

If the *underscore* characters are really dashes reaplace the character in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to remove your special string.

```
NSString *yourString = @"This is your string with speical character --------";
NSCharacterSet *removedCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"--------"];
NSString *finalString = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:removedCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog (@"Your final string : %@", finalString);
```